# How to query out multiple points from a single feature layer and display them?

Tags: point, query, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, graphics

I have a query that goes through and queries points from a single feature layer. the problem I'm having is that it is only grabbing a single point. How do I get it to grab and display all points with the same name? I am using ArcGIS API for JavaScript.

```
function getParkFeature(in_park_name) {
    var symbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_SQUARE, 10,        new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
    new Color([255, 0, 0]), 1),
    new Color([0, 255, 0, 0.25]));
    var query = new Query();
        query.where = "COMMON='" + in_park_name + "'";
        query.outFields = ["COMMON","BOTANICAL", "CONDITION"];
        tree.queryFeatures(query, function (featureSet) {
            console.log(featureSet);
            selectedParkFeature = featureSet.features[0];
            selectedParkDisplayName = in_park_name;
            var graphic = selectedParkFeature;
            graphic.setSymbol(symbol);
            graphic.setInfoTemplate(treesInfoTemplate)
            map.graphics.add(graphic);

    var graphicsExtent = esri.graphicsExtent(map.graphics.graphics)
       if (graphicsExtent !== null) {
            map.setExtent(graphicsExtent);
            map.setExtent(graphicsExtent.expand(3))
       }
    });

}
```

Comment: Provide service would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to loop through the `featureSet` results :

first add to required lib the `dojo/_base/array` `->` ( `Array` in callback function )

```
tree.queryFeatures(query, function (featureSet) {
     map.graphics.clear(); // clear graphics

     Array.forEach(featureSet.features,function(feature){
        selectedParkDisplayName = in_park_name; // unused ??
        var graphic = feature;
        graphic.setSymbol(symbol);
        graphic.setInfoTemplate(treesInfoTemplate)
        map.graphics.add(graphic);
     });

     var graphicsExtent = esri.graphicsExtent(map.graphics.graphics)
     if (graphicsExtent !== null) {
         map.setExtent(graphicsExtent);
         map.setExtent(graphicsExtent.expand(3))
     }
});
```